# Django: Problem with filtering products in order

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to make account view in my django-shop. I want to display information about the order and the ordered goods. I have a ProductInOrder model with foreign key to Order. Now I want to filter the ordered goods by order. But something is going wrong.

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    items = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Cart')
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    buying_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=BUYING_TYPE_CHOICES, 
                                    default='Доставка')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_delivery = models.DateTimeField(default=one_day_hence)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, 
                                default='Принят в обработку')

class ProductInOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    item_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    all_items_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

And views.py

```py
def account_view(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')
    products_in_order = ProductInOrder.objects.filter(order__in=order)
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    instance = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        image_profile = ProfileImage(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)

        if image_profile.is_valid():
            avatar = image_profile.save(commit=False)
            avatar.user = request.user
            avatar.save()
            messages.success(request, 
                f'Ваш аватар был успешно обновлен!')
            return redirect('ecomapp:account')
    else:
        image_profile = ProfileImage()
    context = {
        'image_profile': image_profile,
        'order': order,
        'products_in_order': products_in_order,
        'categories': categories,
        'instance': instance,
    }

    return render(request, 'ecomapp/account.html', context)
```

This line `products_in_order = ProductInOrder.objects.filter(order__in=order)` doesn't work. 
Any help please.

Comment: Does it throw an error or how you see it doesn't work?

Comment: @Clarity It just doesn't work. This line should sort goods belonging to orders

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicityly mention `order_by` in `ProductInOrder` queryset, it will order by its default setup, which is mentioned in `ProductInOrder` model's meta class(if its not mentioned, then default [**`ordering`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#ordering) is `pk`). So using following line should resolve your issue:

```
ProductInOrder.objects.filter(order__in=order).order_by('-order')
```

But an improved answer is like this:

```
products_in_order = ProductInOrder.objects.filter(order__user=request.user).order_by('-order')
```

In this way, you can remove line `order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')` from your code. Whats happening here is that, django allows nested filtering, so you can filter by `order__user` which will allow you order by user from `Order` model. You don't need to make a filter for `Order` separately.

---

**Update:**

I am not sure, probably you are looking for this:(in template)

```
{% for o in order %}

    {% for po in o.productinorder_set.all %}
         {{ po.product }}
         {{ po.item_cost }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Here I am using [**reverse relation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/) between `Order` and `ProductInOrder` here.

Comment: No. The situation is that in order with id=1 I have, for example, 5 goods and so I want them to display in one order. It turns out that the goods must be associated with one order_id. How can I realize this?

Comment: this construction is already exists in my template. It works. Problem is that product_in_order gets unfiltered goods. For example, I chose 2 goods and ordered them. My order has id=1, and 2 ordered goods connected with this id. Next I create one more order with id=2 and choose 5 more goods. But now goods from second order adding to first order id. And it turns out that there are combined same goods in both orders id. They aren't filtered by order id. That's my problem.